# GAE throws IllegalStateException: WRITER

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, groovy, jetty

I have an GAE + Java + Spring app, with very simple controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = ['/_warmup', '/_ah/warmup'])
@ResponseBody
String warmup() {
    return 'OK'
}
```

It just return string, and when i call this url from a browser I get it without a problem.

Btw, when it deployed on GAE, and when it called by gae, i see following exception in logs:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WRITER
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:594)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getOutputStream(ServletResponseWrapper.java:102)
    at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse.getBody(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:64)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:1)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:181)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.writeWithMessageConverters(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:975)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.handleResponseBody(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:933)
```

As I see, I uses same message converter, but always got illegal state of Jetty. Anybody had same issue?

PS when i'm trying to open this url from browser, on production server, it works too. This happens only when this url is called by GAE (cron or warmup request)

Comment: Is that a `public String warmup()` declaration?  Is there some other error occuring that is writing to the output?

Comment: Yes, it's public, and don't see any other errors in output for this requests

Comment: Are you deploying it with Jetty outside of GAE when you say it works without a problem?

Comment: Yes. It's working fine in dev environment (stndard java sdk 1.5.1, that based on jetty). And it's works even on production when i'm calling it from browser

Comment: Doesnt this exception throw when the response is already committed? Perhaps somewhere else in your app the response is being committed. Check filters, interceptors, AOP, etc.

Comment: Right, maybe the flow is somehow different on GAE.  The exception shows that getOutputStream() is being called, but *why* that is happening is the question.  You can't call both getOutputStream() and getWriter() on the Response.

Comment: Oh, Steven, your're right, don't know how i've missed that :( There was a double call from one of filters, that applied only for GAE calls

Comment: Steven, if you put your comment as a answer - i'll accept it. Thanks a lot